# Python file seek and delete a character in a file to format a json

Tags: python, file

I have a file which content is as below:-

```
[
{"Serial Number": "9798128801463", "Company Name": "SAMVEDA ENGLISH", "Employee Markme": "Mark", "Leave": "0"},
{"Serial Number": "9798128805324", "Company Name": "ATHARVEDA ENGLISH", "Employee Markme": "Mark", "Leave": "0"},
{"Serial Number": "9798128819895", "Company Name": "21 SHRESHTHA KAHANIYAN MUDRAKSHAS HINDI", "Employee Markme": "Mark", "Leave": "0"},
]
```

I want to remove the trailing , towards the end of 2nd last line. Can somebody help. I couldn't figure out how to use the seek and truncate to do so

```
[
{"Serial Number": "9798128801463", "Company Name": "SAMVEDA ENGLISH", "Employee Markme": "Mark", "Leave": "0"},
{"Serial Number": "9798128805324", "Company Name": "ATHARVEDA ENGLISH", "Employee Markme": "Mark", "Leave": "0"},
{"Serial Number": "9798128819895", "Company Name": "21 SHRESHTHA KAHANIYAN MUDRAKSHAS HINDI", "Employee Markme": "Mark", "Leave": "0"}
]
```

The result should look like this and then it will be treated as a valid json.

Comment: Is the comma always the same number of characters away from the end of the file, or do you need to search to find it? In other words, is it always a comma, then a newline, then a close bracket, or can the amount of whitespace vary from file to file?

Comment: In some case, I might need to search for the last , from end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly simplified answer that only replaces the last comma in the file with a space rather than removing it (see code comments for explanation):

```
import os


def strip_comma(file_path):
    # open the file in read/write ('r', and '+'), binary ('b') mode
    # 'read' is needed to search for the comma
    # 'write' is needed to replace the comma
    # 'binary' is needed to enable `f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR)`, which moves the cursor relative to its current position
    with open(file_path, 'rb+') as f:
        # go to the end of the file
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        # the current cursor position
        file_length = f.tell()
        
        # loop over ever character except the first
        # this prevents the `f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)` raising an exception when it gets to position -1
        for i in range(file_length - 1):
            # read the current byte
            current_character = f.read(1)
            # if it's a comma, replace it with a space, then exit
            if current_character == b',':
                f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR)
                f.write(b' ')
                break
            # `f.read(1)` move the cursor forward by 1, so we need to go back by 2
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
```

Or if you want to remove the comma rather than replace it, you will have to move the characters after the comma along to fill the space.
The following code reads the last byte in the file, then uses `truncate` to make the file 1 byte shorter, then reads the byte before that and replaces it with the previous last byte, and continues going backwards along the file, moving each byte backwards by 1 position until it reaches a comma, at which point it stops.

```
def strip_comma(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb+') as f:
        f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
        file_length_to_truncate = f.tell()

        current_character = f.read(1)
        f.truncate(file_length_to_truncate)

        while current_character != b',':
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
            old_character = current_character
            current_character = f.read(1)
            f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR)
            f.write(old_character)
```